# Get clients token or force refresh in GCM server side

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Im doing an small cordova APP for android that use GCM plugin to connect to GCM and receive notifications.

I know all the working flow of GCM:

- Server APP start
- Client connect to the server, get the GCM Token and send to the server
- Server store the client token
- Client disconnect
- Server can send push message to the client using the last token saved
- If the client reconnect check the client token to update ir or not in the server

  but I have a special case issue:
- Server APP start
- Client connect to the server, get the GCM Token and send to the server
- Client disconnect
- Server crash, lossing the client tokens
- Server restart, without clien tokens
- Server canT send push to the client because losse the client token, client still listening for push but server cant force them to update.

Exists some method to allow the server reset the client token or get the clients connected to specific GCM APP ID? Because if I need to restar the server and dont save the tokens, i dont know if the client is listening or not, and if the client token expires i never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you persist the token into a database ? Then you won't loose the tokens if the server crashes.

In addition, you can accomplish refreshing invalid tokens by checking the error response from GCM after sending a message to an invalid token, if you get for example Unregistered Device then all you have to do is to remove that token from your database. See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription) and [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)

Comment: Yes i want to save to the database but in the case of the client or GCM reset the client token, the saved one its not the real and I sending push to nothing, if exists a method to send a broadcast to the GCM clients i can send a "reset token" and this can solve my problem, but dont know if is possible

Comment: You can accomplish that by checking the error response from GCM after sending a message to an invalid token, if you get for example Unregistered Device then all you have to do is to remove that token from your database.

See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription) and [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

Comment: I have edited my initial answer, you should mark as it as correct.